# Yii2: how to call action in url with use "pretty url"

Tags: php, controller, yii2, pretty-urls

Without pretty url route has view `http://192.168.100.5/index.php?r=tweet/statistic&from=20160320&to=20160325` and it`s work well.

As docs say when `'enablePrettyUrl' => true`  `/tweet` call default action - and it`s work well also

But for other actions route should be  `/tweet/statistic`. But there is 404 error.

How i can call app\controllers\TweetController  actionStatistic() in this case?

added: i use basic template

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'enableStrictParsing' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
         'controller' => 'tweet'],
        'GET tweet/statistic' => 'tweet/statistic'
    ],
],
```

when i try curl request for `http://192.168.100.5/tweet/statistic`

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

If  `'enablePrettyUrl' => false` and `http://192.168.100.5/index.php?r=tweet/statistic"` it`s work well

Comment: are you still on the REST api? as that changes things a lot.

Comment: have you defined the urlRule in application configuration ? see http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rest-urlrule.html

Comment: Yes i do, but it working only for default action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please mention that this is a rest API, as this changes things a lot. The point is you have to declare the rules so Yii2 will now know how to handle them. You have to tell it what type of request this will be and where the request will go. This is quite different compared to the normal application because this is a rest API.

My working config:

```
 'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                    'controller' => [
                        'v1/client',
..........................
                    ]
                ],
                'GET v1/clients/info' => 'v1/client/info',
                'POST v1/settings/suburb' => 'v1/setting/suburb',
            ],
        ],
```

Comment: i add into my question my `urlManger` and still 404

Comment: Many thanks, your answer help me to where a made mistake)

Comment: Cool, as I was out of ideas.